# How to setup the div border in my case?

Tags: css, html

I have a question regarding the div element border

I am trying to create bunch of `divs` that acts like a `table`

so

```
<div class='div'>first</div>
<div class='div'>second</div>
<div class='div'>third</div>
<div class='div'>four</div>
```

My css is

```
.div{
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

All my divs have borders but the problem is all my divs's top and bottom border are `2 px` instead of `1px` because my css apply `1 px` on every div. The second and the third `div` have thinker border on top and bottom.

I can't really change the class name because it's dynamically generated. Is there anyway to work around this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without more HTML or CSS to go off of, I am guessing you are seeing the effect of each `div` having a full border, and that will be naturally doubled when divs are butted up against eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the top border from every element except of the first one.

```
.div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}
.div:first-child {
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/GzsER/)'s an example of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

did you tryed write something like this :

```
.div {
border:1px solid  black;
border-bottom:0;
}

.div:last-child {
border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your styles.

```
<style>
.div{
border: solid 1px black;
border-bottom:none;
}
.div2{
border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

Then add this to your body:

```
<div class='div'>first</div>
<div class='div'>second</div>
<div class='div'>third</div>
<div class='div2'>four</div>
```

Comment: You can just use the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo class instead of making another class.

Comment: True actually.  Save's one div id to have to change in the future.